# Can there be a greater stylistic differences between Meta and Main site tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, design

When a tag is embedded in a question, it is difficult to determine if it is a main site tag or a meta site tag.

Example:

[image: Similar Tags]

The difference is very minor. One is a slightly darker shade of grey. I have to admit that I didn't even see it on one of my machines. (Apparently the screens aren't calibrated properly)

Can we make this more prominent.

Example question: 
[I'm not a fan of [discussion], are there alternatives we could use?](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1290/im-not-a-fan-of-discussion-are-there-alternatives-we-could-use)

Comment: The darker shade isn't meta vs main.  The shade is to make required tags (which only exist on meta) stand out vs non-required tags.

Comment: In that the case, it's really the same problem. The linked question is a Meta post. `discussion` vs `tags` and `retagging` is very similar.